# Importing CIFAR - 10 Data set to R

Tags: python, r, image-processing

I am trying to download the CIFAR - 10 image data set;
http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html 
 in R but i don't seem to be able to extract the files. I have tried all three formats .bin, .mat and python. Can anybody help with some suggestions of how to extract them ?

Many Thanks, Will

Comment: It doesn't seem to show any data format supported by R. Have you tried using a python interface (like Rpy2) to read python data format through R?

Comment: I have tried a python interface however I have never used the language before so I did not manage to get very far with this. I tried using the example code that was provided for python but couldn't get this to work.

Answer (score 5):

As with anything, I'd say the easiest way would typically be to piggyback on someone else's diligence. For this case, that means looking for someone else who's already converted it. A quick google search renders [this site](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/KernelKnn/vignettes/image_classification_using_MNIST_CIFAR_data.html) (which contains an R data file of the images) a great candidate for that method.

Alternatively, if you want to use the CIFAR-10 data directly, here's a script I just created quickly to read the data in from the binary file that Alex has linked to on [the original page for cifar-10](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html):

```
# Read binary file and convert to integer vectors
# [Necessary because reading directly as integer() 
# reads first bit as signed otherwise]
#
# File format is 10000 records following the pattern:
# [label x 1][red x 1024][green x 1024][blue x 1024]
# NOT broken into rows, so need to be careful with "size" and "n"
#
# (See http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html)
labels <- read.table("cifar-10-batches-bin/batches.meta.txt")
images.rgb <- list()
images.lab <- list()
num.images = 10000 # Set to 10000 to retrieve all images per file to memory

# Cycle through all 5 binary files
for (f in 1:5) {
  to.read <- file(paste("cifar-10-batches-bin/data_batch_", f, ".bin", sep=""), "rb")
  for(i in 1:num.images) {
    l <- readBin(to.read, integer(), size=1, n=1, endian="big")
    r <- as.integer(readBin(to.read, raw(), size=1, n=1024, endian="big"))
    g <- as.integer(readBin(to.read, raw(), size=1, n=1024, endian="big"))
    b <- as.integer(readBin(to.read, raw(), size=1, n=1024, endian="big"))
    index <- num.images * (f-1) + i
    images.rgb[[index]] = data.frame(r, g, b)
    images.lab[[index]] = l+1
  }
  close(to.read)
  remove(l,r,g,b,f,i,index, to.read)
}

# function to run sanity check on photos & labels import
drawImage <- function(index) {
  # Testing the parsing: Convert each color layer into a matrix,
  # combine into an rgb object, and display as a plot
  img <- images.rgb[[index]]
  img.r.mat <- matrix(img$r, ncol=32, byrow = TRUE)
  img.g.mat <- matrix(img$g, ncol=32, byrow = TRUE)
  img.b.mat <- matrix(img$b, ncol=32, byrow = TRUE)
  img.col.mat <- rgb(img.r.mat, img.g.mat, img.b.mat, maxColorValue = 255)
  dim(img.col.mat) <- dim(img.r.mat)

  # Plot and output label
  library(grid)
  grid.raster(img.col.mat, interpolate=FALSE)

  # clean up
  remove(img, img.r.mat, img.g.mat, img.b.mat, img.col.mat)

  labels[[1]][images.lab[[index]]]
}

drawImage(sample(1:(num.images*5), size=1))
```

Hope that helps!